# MongoDb find function to select only specific post

Tags: mongodb

this is the first time im using stack overflow cause i have a problem and i cant find a solucion im just starting out in data bases and im getting this problem.
[image]

The documentation says it should work but when i try to get the posts only with the name post1 y returns both posts.
I might be being stupid but can someone explain why this isnt doing what it should??

Want to only get post1 and not post2 using posts.name: post1, but gave me both posts

Comment: it's in array that's reason you're getting response like that ,you can use the $unwind operator and $match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how Mongo works, the "query" field matches the document, the array field is part of that document so it is returned in full.

What you want to do is use the [$](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) projection operator in your query:

> The positional
> $
> operator limits the contents of an  to return the first element that matches the query condition on the array.

Like so:

```
db.collection.find({
  "posts.name": "post1"
},
{
  "posts.name.$": 1
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qzRaBV-7sCH)

Comment: Another question seeing that you know, How would i not just only get the first value that matches but mutiple, for example if i had two posts with name post1, how would i access multiple??

Comment: I just answered this exact question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74204844/10770370).